# Relative order between Activity's onStart and Fragment's onActivityCreated

Tags: android

Is it possible for an `Activity`'s `onStart` to run bebore its `Fragment`'s `onActivityCreated` in an Android application?

The official doc describes the lifecycle dependency in a way that lets the Fragment know the Activity's status. But it is also helpful if the Activity knows the Fragment's status. How to achieve this?

Comment: why should be helpful for the activity to know the status of a Fragment?

Comment: If you load some data asynchronously in the Activity and want to update the Fragment's UI, for example.

Comment: Centralizing that kind of functionality into an Activity kind of defeats one of the points of Fragments, which is modularizing your code for better reuse and maintenance.

Comment: But if the data is global, isn't it better to keep it in the Activity? You have to load it somewhere, either in the Activity or Fragment.